# What is this bushy rose plant with large pink flowers with many petals?

Tags: identification, roses

My mother had this rose plant for years, it's from the farm she grew up on. When she passed I transferred a piece to my place and it's growing beautifully. She had always just called it an old fashion rose. Can anyone tell me what this rose is?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks as though you have a mulberry growing within the rose as well. Try to remove it as it will grow to compete with this fine rose.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a [damask rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosa_%C3%97_damascena). How lucky! They're used for making rose-based perfumes and rosewater.